# Why is 'nil' not compatible with 'UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform>' in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, cgpath

Trying to create a `CGMutablePath()` as such:

```
let path = CGMutablePath()
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 30, 0)
```

but the compiler keeps on giving me the following error: `'nil' not compatible with expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform>'`. What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to find anything else online. 
(Yes I've tried converting the Ints to CGFloats but it doesn't seem to make a difference.)

Comment: Which Xcode version?

Comment: @MartinR latest beta (Xcode 8 beta 6)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try this:

```
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 0))
```

CGPath APIs are now imported as instance methods in Swift 3.
You can check them with Command-clicking on `CGMutablePath`.
Or see [the latest reference of CGMutablePath](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgmutablepath).

Comment: wow, I'm surprised this works. Any reason why Xcode didn't convert to code to Swift 3?

Comment: @cyril , one reason may be Swift is evolving too fast. So the migrator is a little bit behind the actual behaviour of Swift. And I found this because Swift could not migrate one of my projects. (As you see, you would not check whole migration details, if migration had completely succeeded.)

Answer (score 10):

I was getting this error when trying to draw inside a CGRect

This solved it for me:

```
 let framePath : CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
 framePath.addRect(frameRect)
```

I hope this saves you countless hours trying to solve this. :)