# Swift conversion: ERROR - CGPathAddArc

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am attempting to convert my Swift 2 code into the latest syntax(Swift 3). I am receiving the following error:

**Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'UnsafePointer'**

**(Swift 2 Code)

CGPathAddArc(path, nil, overlayView.frame.width - radius/2 - xOffset, yOffset, radius, 0.0, 2 * 3.14, false)**

Can someone please help me resolve this conversion syntax issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is 'nil' not compatible with 'UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform>' in Swift 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041888/why-is-nil-not-compatible-with-unsafepointercgaffinetransform-in-swift-3)

Comment: There is a new function to replace CGPathAddArc: path.`addArc:withCenter:radius:startAngle:clockwis`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: overlayView.frame.width - radius/2 - xOffset, y: yOffset),
                radius: radius,
                startAngle: 0,
                endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI) * 2,
                clockwise: false)
```