# Nil is not compatible with expected argument

Tags: swift, xcode, path, null, var

I define a CGMutablePath() called path and a SKShapeNode() called rect :

```
    var path = CGMutablePath()
    var path = CGMutablePath()
```

Then I try and display the rectangle :

```
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height/2-36)
    CGPathAddRect(path, nil, rect)
    shapeNode.path = path
    shapeNode.lineWidth = 0
    shapeNode.fillColor = SKColor.black
    shapeNode.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(shapeNode)
```

But I then get the following error :

```
     Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<CGAfineTransform>'
```

At the second line of the previous code :

```
    CGPathAddRect(path, nil, rect)
```

It has only started giving me this error with the swift 3 update, what do I do?

Comment: See [Why is 'nil' not compatible with 'UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform>' in Swift 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39041888/2976878) (dupe, given that one answer shows the use of `addRect`?)

Comment: Another one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508387/1-cgpathmovetopoint-is-unavailable-use-movetotransform-2-cgpathaddlinet.

Comment: Thanks I don't know how I managed to miss those questions when I looked it up...